# What is the difference between the .build, the .csproj and .metaproj files? What's their purpose?

Tags: .net

I am very new to the VS and .NET world.
I am interested in the purposes of these files (whether a viable project should have all of them and what for). The .sln (solution) is generated by VS when creating a new Project/Solution. What about the others?
Even more, I'm not sure where the references for using a certain .NET framework are (so far, I've set it in the .build file, but it doesn't pickup that specified framework).

LE: .csproj "This file will have information about the files included in that project, assemblies used in that project, project GUID and project version etc. This file is related to your project." from [here] ([What does the .csproj file do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446361/what-does-the-csproj-file-do))

Comment: Before posting questions here, you should have read the rules. Being new to something is not an excuse for not having done the effort to type your questions on Google.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my question. It probably is a very dumb question for an experienced person.  I have added a LE for the .csproj. I know how to generate the .metaproj, from [here] (https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/msbuild-and-sln-files/). It seems .metaproj is the converted version of .sln (for what?).  Why do we need these, what do we do with them? (my only programming experience is with C)

Comment: @AlexPirvu developers don't use .metaproj. It is usually a temp file created by MSBuild engine. You should stick to .sln and .csproj. Then buy a good enough MSBuild book to check out all the details.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the suggestion, I will find a book. I am a tester in need of the .build file for running automated plans. So far, we've created the .build files by hand with info on how to run tests, and was wondering how is the .build file created automatically. Trying to generate an .build, I generated .metaproj as described above, and got really confused. Thanks for explaining what is the .metaproj.