# C# missing assembly.cs App.Config and Program.cs

Tags: c#

I submitted this C# assignment in my school and they are using Moodle LMS.

The file that I submitted is `LotterGame.csproj`, I've tested the and run the file before and after submission. I thought it was all good but when my instructor open the file for checking the program doesn't run anymore.

Does anybody know how I can recover this and make this work?

Thanks

Prompt message when I open the .csproj

[image: Prompt message when I open the .csproj]

When I click OK after image above

[image: Missing Reference]

Comment: A `csproj` doesn't contain any source code. You need to give them your whole project folder.

Comment: Is that files available in the file Explorer of your solution folder? If not then copy the solution folder and which will run or get the required files

Answer (score 0):

Prompt message clearly explains the security aspects to the person who is opening the file from unknown source. As long as receiver (school) can trust you, no need to worry.

As `tkausl` rightly said it won't contain any source code.

`.csproj` file contains the list of files and references to assemblies. Best practice is to upload your entire solution to your personal Github and share it with your school.

GitHub link: https://github.com/

I wish your school explained you the basics of project structure. Anyways here is few good reads

[What does the .csproj file do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446361/what-does-the-csproj-file-do)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: Thank you. I’m a beginner in C# the thing is they should inform me that there is something wrong with the file that I submitted and ask me to send this file to make it work and for them to be able to check. I just found out that I got zero on assignment 2 weeks after the submission so I complain to them.